# Progress bar for Image-Upload Nested Component not working

Tags: laravel, progress-bar, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

### The Code

I have extracted the important code, this is not my full code. I have a simple `ImageUpload` Livewire 3 component. I use this as a nested component in my **Listing/** `create.blade.php` View Component:

```html
<form wire:submit="save">
    <livewire:image.image-upload wire:model="image"></livewire:image.image-upload>
</form>
```

So, here is the actual `ImageUpload` Component

```php
class ImageUpload extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;
    #[Validate]
    public $image;
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.image.upload');
    }
    public function updatedImage(): bool
    {
        try{
            $this->validate();
            return true;
        }catch (ValidationException $e) {
            $this->reset('image');
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my **Image/** `upload.blade.php` View Component I have *(Done exactly as in the [documentation](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/uploads#progress-indicators))*:

```html
... 
<form>
<!--            Progress Bar                  -->
    <div
        x-data="{ uploading: false, progress: 0, paused: false }"
        x-on:livewire-upload-start="uploading = true; console.log('started');"
        x-on:livewire-upload-finish="uploading = false; console.log('finished');"
        x-on:livewire-upload-error="uploading = false"
        x-on:livewire-upload-progress="progress = $event.detail.progress"
    >
        <div x-show="uploading">
            <progress max="100" x-bind:value="progress"></progress>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--            Image Input                   -->
    <input type="file" id="image" wire:model="image" class="hidden" 
        x-ref="image" x-on:change="handleImageChange" 
        accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/webp"
    >
    <x-secondary-button type="button" 
        x-on:click.prevent="$refs.image.click();"
    >
        {{ __('Upload a new image') }}
    </x-secondary-button>
    <x-input-error for="image" class="mt-2" />
</form>
...
<script>
/*  Can be ignored, done only for the preview  */
    function handleImageChange(event) {
        const input = event.target;
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (e) => {
            this.imageName = input.files[0].name;
            this.imagePreview = e.target.result;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
</script>
```

### The problem & what I have tried

I have `console.log`s in the `x-on:livewire-upload-start/finish` and they never show up in the console when I upload an image, nor when I load the page and upload for the first time. So, I added this JS code to test it out, to my `<script>` tags:

```js
document.addEventListener('livewire-upload-start', () => {
   console.log('Livewire upload started');
});

document.addEventListener('livewire-upload-progress', (event) => {
   console.log('Livewire upload progress:', event.detail.progress);
});
```

And this works. When I upload a 2MB image I get this printed in the **Console**:

```
Livewire upload started
Livewire upload progress: 19
Livewire upload progress: 20
Livewire upload progress: 29
Livewire upload progress: 45
Livewire upload progress: 61
Livewire upload progress: 79
Livewire upload progress: 99
Livewire upload progress: 100
```

I uploaded 2 consecutive files and it logs each time. I dont have a `submit` on the `form`, because I dont need it, I actually dont even need the `form`. I place the `ImageUpload` component inside a `form` element already (In the **Listing/** `create.blade.php` Livewire View component).

Not really sure how nested components are supposed to work in this case, the Laravel-Livewire documentation is...*Average* to say the least. At this point Im guessing there's something wrong with the `x-show` or the `x-on` in `x-on:livewire-upload-start="uploading = true; console.log('started');"`, because no progress bar is shown, but what could be wrong?

#### The Livewire Documentation

The [Livewire 3 Progress Bar documentation](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/uploads#progress-indicators) is pretty clear and simple, so maybe the nesting is somehow preventing some stuff somehow? I don't know what else to try, I did try some other stuff like making a function in the Component and then submitting to that, while I use Debugbar, but to no avail, nothing gets sent back. Is it something to do with the `form` element?

I tried it without the `form`, still the same. I need to use the `updatedImage()`. I had the idea where I change the code of the `<x-secondary-button>` so that it submits to a function in the `ImageUpload` Component, as well as a `wire:submit` on the `form`, nothing